# Convert Persian date to Julian or Gregorian with keith wood calendars

Tags: javascript, date

I created a date object with [Keith Wood calendar library](https://github.com/kbwood/calendars) with Persian instant:

```
var d = $.calendars.newDate(1393, 5, 6, 'persian', 'fa');
```

Now I need to get Julian or Gregorian date from this date but when I use `.toJD()` function it returns Julian date that does not equal to current date in

```
 var e = d.toJD();
 console.log(e)
```

so how do i fix this problem? I've created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/quguto/1/) for this problem .

Comment: Have you tried d.toJSDate()?

Comment: @Pablo it try your way and it returned `Sat May 25 1393 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)` but the year still 1393 but i need it 2014.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can find examples of transformation in the  Keith Wood's web

Comment: @MBehtemam  Here is my method to convert Persian Dates to any other calendars without external libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421825/how-to-convert-persian-jalali-dates-to-other-18-calendar-dates-in-javascript-w/71421832#71421832

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `toJD()` is not what you need:

```
var d = $.calendars.newDate(1388, 1, 1, 'persian', 'fa');
console.log("Persian date: "+d.toLocaleString()); // Persian date: 1388-01-01
var e = d.toJSDate();
console.log(e); // Sat Mar 21 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

UPDATE: For your comment I see the issue is not solved with this because it transforms the Persian date to your locale date. As far as I can see in the library's reference, there is no way to tell to that function which locale should be used. So the correct way, as the [author's provided demo shows](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsBasics.html), is creating another target calendar and pass the current one as parameter:

```
var d = $.calendars.newDate(1388, 1, 1, 'persian', 'fa');
var e = $.calendars.newDate(d, 'gregorian', 'fa');
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to converting a Persian date to any other calendar date is to use the ECMAScript proposal "[Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)" which is currently in Stage 3 of Active Proposals.

The following function will convert a Persian date to any of the 18 available calendars in Javascript. The default is conversion to the Gregorian date.

You can specify the target Calendar to convert to and also the formatting and locale to use:

```html
<script type='module'>
// ====== load Temp polyfill (not needed after implementation) ========
    import * as TemporalModule from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@js-temporal/polyfill@0.3.0/dist/index.umd.js'
//=====================================================================


//---------------------------------------
function persianToCalendars(Y, M, D, options={}) {
return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(options.locale??="en",options).format(new Date(temporal.Temporal.PlainDateTime.from({year:Y,month:M,day:D,calendar:'persian'}).toString().split("[")[0]));
}
//---------------------------------------


console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6));    // default

console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6,{dateStyle: "full"}));

console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6,{locale: "fa"}));

console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6,{dateStyle:"full", locale: "fa"}));

console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6,{calendar:"islamic", dateStyle:"full"}));   // to islamic full 'en' locale

console.log(persianToCalendars(1400,12,6,{locale:"fa", calendar:"islamic", dateStyle:"full"}));  // to islamic 'fa' locale


</script>
```