# group dates by week javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, group-by

I have the array of Persian dates and I want to group dates by the week.
for example, I have the following array:

```
[
    "1396-10-11 09:07:21",
    "1396-10-10 10:03:51",
    "1396-10-07 02:07:02",
    "1396-11-27 08:02:45",
    "1396-11-19 01:02:32",
    "1396-12-01 22:13:21",
    "1396-02-12 09:07:21",
    "1396-05-18 04:02:29",
    "1396-05-21 14:01:42",
    "1396-07-11 01:16:29"
]
```

and I want to groupBy dates by the week.

I wrote following code but not working good:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    var val = item[prop];
    groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
    groups[val].push(item);
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

const formatted = dates.map(elem => {
  return { 
    numberOfWeek: moment(elem.date, 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD').startOf('jMonth').jWeek(),
    date: moment(elem.date, 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD').format('jYYYY-jMM-jDD'), 
    score: elem.score 
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?  Also for that array what is the desired output?

Comment: You should start by parsing the dates. Once you've shown you can do that, here's a pretty lengthy thread on determining the week of the year a day is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

For grouping by, you can probably use an object with the week number as the keys.

These are just ideas on how I'd do it. Like @chris said, please show us what you've tried and we can go from there.

Comment: @chris my code added

Comment: There is an answer here that gets the year and week number for any date: [*Get week of year in JavaScript like in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php). However, you'll still need to correctly parse the input string to a Date.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [moment().week()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get the week number of the year and then group by it, here is a working example, I used [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new object of dates grouped by the week number:

```js
const dates = [
  "1396-10-11 09:07:21",
  "1396-10-10 10:03:51",
  "1396-10-07 02:07:02",
  "1396-11-27 08:02:45",
  "1396-11-19 01:02:32",
  "1396-12-01 22:13:21",
  "1396-02-12 09:07:21",
  "1396-05-18 04:02:29",
  "1396-05-21 14:01:42",
  "1396-07-11 01:16:29"
];

const groups = dates.reduce((acc, date) => {

  // create a composed key: 'year-week' 
  const yearWeek = `${moment(date).year()}-${moment(date).week()}`;
  
  // add this key as a property to the result object
  if (!acc[yearWeek]) {
    acc[yearWeek] = [];
  }
  
  // push the current date that belongs to the year-week calculated befor
  acc[yearWeek].push(date);

  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @YouneL but if I have a date for years ago, what happens?!

Comment: In this case you have to group dates by week number and year, use moment(date).format('YYYY') to get the year and concatente with the week number and then group, hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain more about how to combine the week and the year?

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look. if my answer was useful for you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks @YouneL but why  "1396-11-27 08:02:45" and "1396-12-01 22:13:21" dates are in the same group?

Comment: because they are on the same week 49 of year 1396

Comment: Between these 2 dates are 1 month and 20 days difference!!

Comment: no they are 4 days :) `1396-11-28,1396-11-29,1396-11-30,1396-12-01`

Comment: in your code output "1396-11-27 08:02:45" and "1396-12-01 22:13:21" dates are in the same group

Comment: Yes that's because they belong to the same week (49) of the year, what's wrong with this ? they have 4 days difference

Answer (score 11):

Another simple way of achieving the same with Lodash would be as follows:

```js
const groupBy = require('lodash/groupBy');
const moment = require('moment');
const data = [
   "1396-10-11 09:07:21",
   "1396-10-10 10:03:51",
   "1396-10-07 02:07:02",
   "1396-11-27 08:02:45",
   "1396-11-19 01:02:32",
   "1396-12-01 22:13:21",
   "1396-02-12 09:07:21",
   "1396-05-18 04:02:29",
   "1396-05-21 14:01:42",
   "1396-07-11 01:16:29"
];

groupBy(data, (dt) => moment(dt).week());
```

Result is as follows:

```js
{ 
  '7': [ '1396-02-12 09:07:21' ],
  '21': [ '1396-05-18 04:02:29', '1396-05-21 14:01:42' ],
  '29': [ '1396-07-11 01:16:29' ],
  '41': [ '1396-10-07 02:07:02' ],
  '42': [ '1396-10-11 09:07:21', '1396-10-10 10:03:51' ],
  '47': [ '1396-11-19 01:02:32' ],
  '49': [ '1396-11-27 08:02:45', '1396-12-01 22:13:21' ] 
}
```

Comment: This seem a decent one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a vanilla JavaScript solution like I was, I managed to adapt the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084188/6760186) to replace moment.js with pure vanilla code. I also had to make use of the suggesstion of a PersionDate class from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61158379/6760186) in another question.

For gregorian calender you simply replace `PersianDate` by the default `Date` class

```js
class PersianDate extends Date {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    toLocaleDateString = () => super.toLocaleDateString('fa-IR-u-nu-latn');
    getParts = () => this.toLocaleDateString().split("/")
    getDay = () => super.getDay() === 6 ? 0 : super.getDay() + 1
    getDate = () => this.getParts()[2];
    getMonth = () => this.getParts()[1] - 1;
    getYear = () => this.getParts()[0];
    getMonthName = () => this.toLocaleDateString("fa-IR", { month: 'long' });
    getDayName = () => this.toLocaleDateString("fa-IR", { weekday: 'long' });
}

const dates = [
  "1396-10-11 09:07:21",
  "1396-10-10 10:03:51",
  "1396-10-07 02:07:02",
  "1396-11-27 08:02:45",
  "1396-11-19 01:02:32",
  "1396-12-01 22:13:21",
  "1396-02-12 09:07:21",
  "1396-05-18 04:02:29",
  "1396-05-21 14:01:42",
  "1396-07-11 01:16:29"
];

const groups = dates.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const date = new PersianDate(curr);
  const startOfYearDate = new PersianDate(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  const weekOfYear = Math.ceil(Math.floor((date.getTime() - startOfYearDate.getTime()) /
    (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 7);

  // create a composed key: 'year-week' 
  const yearWeek = `${date.getFullYear()}-${weekOfYear}`;
  
  // add this key as a property to the result object
  if (!acc[yearWeek]) {
    acc[yearWeek] = [];
  }
  
  // push the current date that belongs to the year-week calculated befor
  acc[yearWeek].push(curr);

  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(groups);
```