# Convert date locale in google sheet from Gregorian calendar to Jalali calendar

Tags: function, date, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondered if it's possible in google sheet to convert Gregorian calendar to jalali using a function. In fact, I have some date such as :

```
February 20, 2021 4:30 AM
```

I need to display this date in it's front cell in Jalali format (without time) which is :

```
1399/12/02
```

or:

```
Esfand 02, 1399
```

As I've mentioned, I need both c Gregorian and Jalali calendars in same sheet in diffrent cells. Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without scripts you can try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(A1:A3), {ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE("01/01/"&YEAR(TODAY()))&":"&
 DATEVALUE("12/31/"&YEAR(TODAY())))), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://calendar.zoznam.sk/persian_calendar-en.php?ly="&YEAR(TODAY()), "//tr"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null"), 
 ": (.+)"), " ", ", "), "\., ", " ")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(A1:A3), {ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE("01/01/"&YEAR(TODAY()))&":"&
 DATEVALUE("31/12/"&YEAR(TODAY())))), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://calendar.zoznam.sk/persian_calendar-en.php?ly="&YEAR(TODAY()), "//tr"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null"), 
 ": (.+)"), " ", ", "), "\., ", " ")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### REVERSE:

[How to convert Persian (Shamsi) date to Gregorian (Miladi) date with Function Script in Excel or Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517958/how-to-convert-persian-shamsi-date-to-gregorian-miladi-date-with-function-sc)

Comment: Does not work. returns empty cell

Comment: @nimasp answer updated

Comment: I cannot use this function. It returns nothing, actually. What is the problem?? it's the function problem, or I'm using it in the wrong way??

Comment: @Solat can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 16):

#### You can create your own custom function in Apps Script and later use it in Google Sheets.

You will have to start by going to **Tools** > **Script editor**.

Afterwards, you can apply the method used by [AmirFo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7580839/amir-fo) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61158379) and create a function like this:

```
function CONVERT_DATE(date) {
  let jalaliFormat = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('fa-IR').replace(/([۰-۹])/g, token => String.fromCharCode(token.charCodeAt(0) - 1728));
  return jalaliFormat;
}
```

To make use of this formula, simply type it in your Google Sheets as a regular formula by calling `=CONVERT_DATE`.

#### Before

[image: before formula]

#### After

[image: after using the custom function]

#### Note

Please check your `appsscript.json` file to make sure you have the correct timezone there, otherwise you might be getting a date +/-1 days.

#### Reference

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions);
- [How to change Gregorian date to Persian date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570884/how-to-change-gregorian-date-to-persian-date-in-javascript/53894209).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It worked. However, It's really weird that I have two different output in different cells !! for instant February 13, 2021 4:15 PM will convert to 1399/11/24 in a cell and in another cell, it will be converted to 1399/11/25  !!!  Do you know why ?

Comment: Just like mentioned above, please check the appsscript.json manifest file of your project and adjust the timezone accordingly.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks. BTW, would you please let me know how to check/set timezone in appsscript.json. Thanks

Comment: I found it . Thank you very much

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the correct answer. The other answer depends on an external php file running, which I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: @ale13 By the way, I can't find that `appsscript.json` file, where is it located?