# How to convert Persian (Shamsi) date to Gregorian (Miladi) date with Function Script in Excel or Google Sheet?

Tags: excel, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to convert a Persian date to a Gregorian date using an **Excel / Google Sheet function**?
for example:

```
1401/06/06
```

to:

```
2022/08/28
```

P.S: Earlier I found a function to convert Gregorian to Jalali written by [Amir Fo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61158379/19863011), But my question is about converting from Persian (Shamsi) to Gregorian.

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pure Excel solution, which does not require an internet connection or Power Query.

**Disclaimer:** I've found the function [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8802e5b-9f86-4079-a28b-da4bb80ddd63/convert-shamsi-date-to-gregorian?forum=excel) and made some modifications to make it more readable. BTW, I've tested the function for the period `1396/07/01` to `1401/07/01` and it works OK, but use it with extensive testing and at your own risk.

Basically, the function calculates the total days since `1278/10/11` Shamsi (which is equal to the Excel date origin, `1900-01-01`). The result of the function is an integer (date value).

Below, you will find the solution  in two formats, one using the new [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function (for Excel 2021 and Office 365) and one without:

Note that the Shamsi date should be in the format `1401/07/21`.

Using `LET`:

```
=LET(
  y,VALUE(LEFT(A1,4)),
  m,VALUE(MID(A1,6,2)),
  d,VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)),
  full_months,IF((m-1)<7,(m-1)*31,IF((m-1)>6,(m-1)*30+6)),
  total,(y-1)*365+full_months+d+INT((y-1)/4),
  IF(MOD(y,4)=0,total+1,total)-466710
)
```

Legacy version:

```
IF(
  MOD(VALUE(LEFT(A1,4)),4)=0,
  (VALUE(LEFT(A1,4))-1)*365+(
    IF(
      (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)<7,
      (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)*31,
      IF(
        (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)>6,
        (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)*30+6
      )
    )
  )+VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))+INT((VALUE(LEFT(A1,4))-1)/4)+1,
  (VALUE(LEFT(A1,4))-1)*365+(
    IF(
      (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)<7,
      (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)*31,
      IF(
        (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)>6,
        (VALUE(MID(A1,6,2))-1)*30+6
      )
    )
  )+VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))+INT((VALUE(LEFT(A1,4))-1)/4)
)-466710
```

To convert the resulting integer to date, either change the cell format to `Date` or use the following formula:

```
TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: Try for example to convert 1412/05/01 from Persian (Jalali) to Gregorian. Via this formula it returns 2033-07-23, while it should be 2033-07-22. Any idea why?

Comment: @MohsenKarbassi It is probably due to leap years, but I haven't done extensive research to identify the cause of the problem. There are periods where the formula can be off by a day or two, and then there are correct periods. That's why I added the disclaimer at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP("Gregorian calendar", IMPORTHTML("https://date-today.com/en/shamsi-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\/(\d+)")*1&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\/(\d+)\/")*1&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\d{4}")*1&"-to-gregorian-calendar.html", "table", 1), 2, ), 
 "e/mm/dd")
```

[image]

or:

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP("Gregorian calendar", IMPORTHTML("https://date-today.com/en/shamsi-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\d+")*1&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\/(\d+)\/")*1&"-"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\d{4}")*1&"-to-gregorian-calendar.html", "table", 1), 2, ), 
 "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

[image]

---

### REVERSE:

[Convert date locale in google sheet from Gregorian calendar to Jalali calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315919/convert-date-locale-in-google-sheet-from-gregorian-calendar-to-jalali-calendar/66324100#66324100)

Comment: Can you please share an example in google sheets? Currently, this formula is not working for me @player0

Comment: @MahdiOmrani sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jc0v8MaSVWuf1by82Nr6I4SUkb0MSVf8r-5j8tS2xZ4/copy

Comment: To get `day` of a date like 1402/10/19, use `\/(\d+)$` in order to get latest part

Answer (score 3):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens, over on the right under Applied Steps, the second step will be `#"Changed Type"`

  - Edit that step to add `fa-IR` as the culture

    ```
      #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}} , "fa-IR")
    ```

    - *This is the same as Changed Type with locale using Persian as the locale*

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work on Google Sheets

Comment: @MahdiOmrani  Of course not. Power Query is a feature of Excel.  You asked for a solution in Excel **OR** Sheets. Note that the previous answer will not work in Excel.

Comment: Don't you have a query that works in Google Sheets also? @Ron

Comment: @MahdiOmrani if you need to do it as a query in sheets, I suggest you adapt the algorithm shown you in the previous answer to a script that will run in sheets. Then post back or ask a new question, if you are having difficulty with that script. Be sure to tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Excel supports all calendar conversion.
The key is to follow procedures one by one.

suppose We want to convert cell `A1`=`10/10/1401` from Persian calendar to English Calendar and set the result in the Cell `B1`

**Step 1:**

Right Click on `B1` > `Format cells...` from `Number` tab in the `category` select `Date` and change it to desire calendar type, in this case `English`.
For B1 also type the formula `=A1`.

**Step 2:**

Right click on `A1` > `Format cells...` from `Number` tab in the `category` select `Date` and change the calendar type to whatever your date type is; in this case `Persian`.

Tick the check mark `input dates according to selected calendar`

**Step 3:**

Enter your Persian date in cell `A1`. You'll get the converting date in cell `B1`.

*Be aware of the order you enter the `year` and `month` and the `day`.*